# Mailkit. What is the best way to move an existing folder with all it's subfolders and messages to another?

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I'm trying to move the existing folder to another one using MailKit library. Currently I'm doing it manually by re-creating the same folders structure in new location, but it doesn't seem as a good solution because I also need to track all subscriptions, subfolders attributes etc. I'm wondering if there any way to make life easier?

Thanks

Here is a sample code:

```
private async Task MoveFolderToRecursively(IMailFolder sourceFolder, IMailFolder destinationFolder)
        {
            await sourceFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

            var messages = await sourceFolder.FetchAsync(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
            var uids = messages.Select(x => x.UniqueId).ToList();

            await sourceFolder.MoveToAsync(uids, destinationFolder);

            if (sourceFolder.IsSubscribed)
            {
                await destinationFolder.SubscribeAsync();
            }

            await sourceFolder.CloseAsync(true);

            if (sourceFolder.Attributes.HasFlag(FolderAttributes.HasChildren))
            {
                var subfolders = sourceFolder.GetSubfolders();
                foreach (var subfolder in subfolders)
                {
                    var destinationSubfolder = destinationFolder.Create(subfolder.Name, true);
                    await MoveFolderToRecursively(subfolder, destinationSubfolder);
                }
            }

            await sourceFolder.DeleteAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the folder instead of cloning it.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast. But what if I need to move some folder to other subfolder?

E.g. I need to move the folder **a/subfolder1/subfolder2**  to **b/subfolder1**.
_ImapFolder.Rename_ method accepts the original folder as a first parameter and new name of the folder as a second. And the new name should not be a fullname, 
Mailkit throws an exception and doesn't accept the directory separator symbol.

Comment: No, why would the rename method require the original folder that you are about to rename? An instance method ALREADY HAS THAT INFO. The folder argument to Rename() is the new parent folder. In other words: `subfolder2.Rename (b, "subfolder1");`